# Append a list on a condition?

Tags: python

I have two lists as follows:

```py
A = ["Ram","Joseph","Arman","Ravi", "Sundar","Sushmita"]
B = ["Su","Ra"]
```

I want to create another list named C and want to append items of A provided , maximum only one name can b appended if it starts with any elements of B.

So in this case, desired result should be

```py
C= ["Ram","Joseph","Arman", "Sundar"]
```

"Ravi" and "Sushmita" shall not be appended to C list since it starts with "Ra" and "Su" for which already "Ram" and "Sundar" have been appended to C.
I am aware about the count feature in list , but not able to use it here.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this issue already? Do you have a sample code we can help to improve?

Comment: can you give more info : you want append two list and delete some index start by Ra and Su ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a double iteration where you would iterate through both `A` and `B`. You can append values to C if a string from `B` is in `A`.

#### Example solution

```py
x = ["random", "test", "three"]
e = ["ran", "te"]
c = []
for item_in_x in x:
    for item_in_e in e:
        if item_in_e in item_in_x:
            c.append(item_in_x)
```

#### Output

```
['random', 'test']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `set` data structure.

```py
A = ["Ram","Joseph","Arman","Ravi", "Sundar","Sushmita"]
B = ["Su","Ra"]
usedPatterns = set()
C = []
for string in A:
    foundPattern = None
    for pattern in B:
        if string.startswith(pattern):
            foundPattern = pattern
            break
    if foundPattern is None: # If pattern not found, append to C
        C.append(string)
    elif foundPattern not in usedPatterns: # If pattern found and not used before, append to C
        usedPatterns.add(foundPattern)
        C.append(string)

print(C)
```

---

Output

```
['Ram', 'Joseph', 'Arman', 'Sundar']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = ["Ram","Joseph","Arman","Ravi", "Sundar","Sushmita"]
B = ["Su","Ra"]
C = []
D = []
repeat = False

for a in A:
    for d in D:
        if d == a[:len(d)]:
            repeat = True
            break
    if not repeat:
        for b in B:
            if b == a[:len(b)]:
                D.append(b)
                break
        C.append(a)
    repeat = False

print(C)
```

Output:

`['Ram', 'Joseph', 'Arman', 'Sundar']`